# Problems with getting right cornerRadius for a different size of the screen

Tags: ios

I have a problem with my application.
In it I want to have 12 round buttons for choosing color. I used IUButton to do this.
Then I used auto layout constrains so the the app will look the same on different sizes of iPhone screen. And here I face a problem:

When I select in simulated metrics in IB "inferred" size of the screen, only 4 inch screen has a circle button.Other, bigger iPhone sizes are showing rectangle buttons with rounded corners.

It looks like the button is resized but is still using the smaller cornerRadius(of a 4 inch iPhone), though the width and height have changed.

But when I choose the same size in simulated metrics and in simulator I have a desired result.

And I have no idea what to do with that! Here is a part of code I am using  to make circle buttons. I really hope for help! I really hope that its not a duplicate.

In other words if I don't choose the view in the metric size I get rounded corners, but not the circles. If I choose the same size iPhone in simulator everything is fine (as needed). But I need to have circles while the metrics size is set to inferred.

Here is part of the code I am using:

```c
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    self.isCurrencySelect = NO;
    [self createCardTypeList];
    self.currencyList = [FinanceUtils currencyCodeListWithAppendedName:NO];
    self.pickerContainerView.hidden = YES;

    [self.cardTypeButton setTitle:CARDTYPENAME forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.currencyButton setTitle:CARDCURRENCYNAME forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    self.cardBackgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
    self.cardBackgroundView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    self.cardBackgroundView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.cardBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorFromHexString:@"#502CA7"];

    //change placeholder color
    [self.cardNameTextField setValue:[UIColor darkGrayColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
    [self.incomeTextField setValue:[UIColor darkGrayColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];

    //set cards value
    self.moneySpentValueLabel.text = @"0";
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self updateButtonsColor];
}

-(void) updateButtonsColor{
    NSArray *buttonsColorArray = [UIColor cardsColorArray];

    for(UIButton *btn in self.buttonsArray){

        btn.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;

        btn.layer.cornerRadius = btn.frame.size.width/2;

        btn.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        btn.backgroundColor  = [buttonsColorArray objectAtIndex:btn.tag];
     }
}
```

Comment: Hello, several suggestions:
1) Never set the value like this: `cornerRadius = 10.0f`, if you not sure that the frameSize U applied this value to is equal to (20,20). Your `btn.frame.size.width/2` looks Ok
2) The frames of the subviews aren't yet set in the `viewWillAppear:`
The appropriate method to modify your UI before the view is presented to the screen is: `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: Thanks man! All made by your suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corner radius should not be a constant, try changing it to the button height or something like that.